# How to solve this partial fraction decomposition for taking the Inverse Laplace Transform?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions

I am trying to solve the differential equation $y''+16y=2\sin(4x)$ with initial conditions of $y(0)=\frac{-1}{2}$ and $y'(0)=0$. Upon solving for $\mathcal{L}\{y\}$, I obtained the below fraction. 
$$\frac{1}{(s^2+16)^2} $$
And I need to solve this fraction using partial fraction decomposition to make it look like one of the forms in the Laplace Transform Table so I can take the Inverse Laplace Transform to solve the differential equation. Please help me!

Comment: It's already in fully simplified form.  That is, $A=0$ and $B=1$.

Comment: The decomposition would actually be $\dfrac{As + B}{s^2+16} + \dfrac{Cs + D}{(s^2+16)^2}$.  But like SBA said, it's already fully simplified as originally given.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt r               I am solving a differential equation using Laplace Transform. One of the fractions is the above. I need to make it look like one of the forms in the Laplace Transform Table.

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to use convolutions.

Comment: Well, if you really wanted to, you could factor over the complex numbers:$$s^2+4^2=(s-4i)(s+4i)$$But I wouldn't recommend that.  A better alternative would be to notice that$$\frac1{(s^2+16)^2}=-\frac d{ds}\frac1{s+16}$$

Comment: Anyways, that's a completely different question.  Might want to make a new post and delete this one, or editing this one up.

Comment: Oops, my derivative is wrong.  But see the link @msm commented, it carries what I meant to say.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments we see that what you actually want is the inverse Laplace transform of $\dfrac1{(s^2+16)^2}$.  You'll need to use the convolution theorem, which essentially (details withheld) says: $$ f \ast g = \mathcal L^{-1}\left\{ \mathcal L\{f\} \cdot \mathcal L\{g\}\right\}$$

In this case, you'll want to take $\mathcal L\{f\} = \mathcal L\{g\} = \dfrac1{s^2+16}$.  This means that $f = g$.  Find the $f$ that gives you $\mathcal L\{f\} = \dfrac1{s^2+16}$ and then find $f \ast f$, where $\ast$ is the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Comment: Easier than convolution is to use properties of LT [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2056978/350875)

Comment: @msm, easier is largely subjective, and I saw you already linked this in the comments.  Now OP has two ways to do it.  :)  Hope that downvote isn't yours, though.

Comment: what does op mean??

Comment: @socrates, in this context, OP = original poster.

Comment: @tilper No it is not my downvote, convolution can also be used (+1).