# How to find the Laplace transform of $f(t)=t e^t$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How to find the Laplace transform of the following function:
$$f(t)=t e^t$$
$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty (te^t e^{-st})dt$$
What method do I use to find the integral?

Comment: Try a computer algebra program, like wxMaxima.

Comment: integration by parts (combine the e-powers first, remember, you are integrating w.r.t. $x$, not $s$)

Comment: Combine the exponentials and use integration by parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:
$$ f(t) = t e^t $$
So the Laplace transform of this function is:
\begin{align*}
F(s) &= \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \} \\
&= \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty t e^{t} e^{-st} \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty t e^{(1-s)t} \, dt \\
&= \lim_{b \to \infty} \left[ \int_0^b t e^{(1-s)t} \, dt \right] \\
&= \lim_{b \to \infty} \left(\left[ t \cdot \frac{1}{1-s}e^{(1-s)t} \right]_{t=0}^b - \int_0^b \frac{1}{1-s}e^{(1-s)t} \, dt\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-s}\lim_{b \to \infty} \left(b e^{(1-s)b} - \int_0^b e^{(1-s)t} \, dt\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{s-1}\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b e^{(1-s)t} \, dt & (s > 1) \\
&= \frac{1}{s-1}\lim_{b \to \infty} \left[\frac{1}{1-s} e^{(1-s)t} \right]_0^b & (s > 1) \\
&= \frac{1}{(s-1)^2}\lim_{b \to \infty} \left[1-e^{(1-s)b} \right] & (s > 1) \\
&= \frac{1}{(s-1)^2} & (s > 1)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

To do it without integral (as in my comment in your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2284282/350875)), using properties of LT:

> $$tf(t)\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}\longleftrightarrow-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}F(s)$$

Here $f(t)=e^t$ whose Laplace transform is $F(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}$.

The Laplace transform of $te^t$ becomes $$-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right)=\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}$$